# ASP.NET MVC Model - Strange Behaviour

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm pulling my hair out with this one. I'm getting the build error everytime my repository or form view model references aspnet_UsersInRoles:

> Error 8 'Emas.Model.aspnet_User' does
>   not contain a definition for
>   'aspnet_UsersInRoles' and no extension
>   method 'aspnet_UsersInRoles' accepting
>   a first argument of type
>   'Emas.Model.aspnet_User' could be
>   found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Administrator\Desktop\IRenewables_EMAS\IRenewables_EMAS\Models\Repositories\SecurityRepository.cs    57  22  IRenewables_EMAS

---

This is really odd because when I loop into my Model everything is fine the relationship is on place. I've tried everything i can think of, removing the object from the model and refreshing, then dragging it back in etc etc.

The only thing i did different with this MVC App is I have decided to drop the GUID field from UserId. I don't think its anything to do with that - something more simple. Should be a simple obvious fix this but i'm going babanas with this one - any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: You dropped the UserID? In which table? You can't drop a field from a field (UserID is a field). Simple test, if you undo the modification, does it work again?

Answer (score 1):

Sussed it, I did not have a compound primary key set on the aspnet_Roles table, DOH